# What is the correct input to LSTM?

Tags: graph, pytorch, lstm, data-mining

I have tensors of varying length . These tensors are data for different time period. My aim is to get final output of the lstm.

```
torch.randn(4)-Time1
torch.randn(3,4)-Time2
torch.randn(4,4)-Time3
```

These are my  data, what is the input to LSTM from here?  , my aim is to get the final output from the lstm

For example, this is what I did

```
out_position = self.linear_out_position(features)
    _, (hn, _) = self.lstm(out_position)
        output = self.ffn(hn)
```

however i am getting result for each tensor, how can i only get the final result? Please I need your help

Answer (score 1):

You can access the last hidden layer as hn[-1]
`output = self.ffn(hn[-1])`

Comment: Thank you @fatima, so do I need to combine these tensor to one tensor before input to LSTM? or I can just  use each time  as input?

Comment: You need to combine them as input. But you have to use padding in your tensors and bring them into same shape first. Then you can use torch.cat to combine the inputs.